# Switching asp.net Core Blazor hosting models

Tags: blazor

I am doing a research on Asp.net blazor, and I have found an article on Blazor hosting.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-3.0

I am interested to find out how difficult would be to switch from server-side Blazor hosting model to client-side and other way arround?

Answer (score 11):

It's not difficult at all. Robin Sue has already got this working and I would suggest checking out his [Blazor Dual mode](https://github.com/Suchiman/BlazorDualMode) repo. Here are his instructions for adding dual mode.

Create a Blazor (ASP.NET Core hosted) Project, then change the Startup class of the .Server Project to enable server side features. This doesn't have adverse effects on Client Side Blazor but enables the Server Side services. For that you need to have `services.AddServerSideBlazor();` in ConfigureServices and `endpoints.MapBlazorHub<Client.App>("app")`; in Configure

We can now serve Client Side and Server Side apps but we need to polyfil the HttpClient that is provided in DI in Client Side by default. Server Side doesn't register it by default so we detect this and then register an HttpClient in DI that behaves similiar for compatibility

```
// Server Side Blazor doesn't register HttpClient by default
if (!services.Any(x => x.ServiceType == typeof(HttpClient)))
{
    // Setup HttpClient for server side in a client side compatible fashion
    services.AddScoped<HttpClient>(s =>
    {
        // Creating the URI helper needs to wait until the JS Runtime is initialized, so defer it.
        var uriHelper = s.GetRequiredService<IUriHelper>();
        return new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(uriHelper.GetBaseUri())
        };
    });
}
```

At this point, the only difference is which blazor JS file we load in the browser. This can be either achieved by serving a different index.html (for which i couldn't see an easy way) or using a small piece of JS to decide which file to load

```
<script id="blazorMode"></script>
<script>
    document.getElementById("blazorMode").src = window.location.search.includes("mode=server") ? "_framework/blazor.server.js" : "_framework/blazor.webassembly.js";
</script>
```

Once again this is all work by **[Robin Sue](https://github.com/Suchiman)** and full credit goes to him.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to switch from one hosting model to another, and your application is made of the Blazor template (selected hosting model is not important), then this can be very easy. Look for answers in this section how to switch from one model to another.

But, as you add functionalities to your app, things become more complicated, and the swap gradually become more and more difficult.

Personally, I think that the idea of switching from one hosting model to another should be rejected, meaning that you must decide before hand which hosting model can serve you better, and  once you've made up your mind, you develop your app without any constraints that you may impose on your app just because you are likely to switch the hosting model.

**UPDATE**

The following are some examples of how switching from one mode of execution to another can be complicated and even impossible.

Suppose you've decided to use client-side Blazor, and to implement authentication using Jwt, and objects provided by the Blazor framework, such as AuthenticationStateProvider. Now, switching to server-side Blazor can be problematic. Not only is it absurd to use Jwt authentication on the server, and send the Jwt token to the user's browser, but also it may introduce security vulnerabilities, needless to say you'll have to change your code, and so on.

Another example, suppose you've decide to built your app with server-side application, and you're using services from your Components to retrieve data. Once you decide to switch to client-side Blazor, these services, alas, are rendered useless: you can't access your server, say located in the USA, from your browser, say, in the UK. You now need to switch to using HTTP Ajax calls ( HttpClient ) in order to retrieve your data residing on your server. That is, you have to rewrite a great deal of your code, etc.

These were two examples why you shouldn't entertain the idea of switching from one hosting model to another. It is a bad idea, and there is no magic way to do it. I do not recommend it.

**NEW UPDATE** Please, read the last portion of my answer. It make it clear what are the problems you may face, and the code changes you'll have to employ, etc.

I guess you're new to Blazor, and you try to understand the benefits of switching from one mode of execution to another. I've given your some examples, and have heartily rejected the idea of switching from one mode of execution to another. I guess the best way for you to solve this is to start learning Blazor. Please ask me specific questions, so I can answer you more to the point.

Hope this helps...

Comment: My quesion is maybe unclear. Migration is also an option or code duplication.

Comment: See new update above...

Comment: Well, i was driven by the question of what would be the cost of switching between two in case of wrong initial setup

Comment: I've given two examples in my answer from which you can infer this cost... See the bold title Update...

Comment: After carefully reading your answer and doing some additional research i dont think it is a big of a deal to switch host models if code is smartly organized.